# Unable to show a List<> of objects inside my view

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, html-helper, asp.net-mvc-5

I am working on an asp.net mvc-4 web application. and i want to send a list of objects to my view and show them using `Html.Display` and `Html.Editor` templates .. but the value will be empty.

Here is my model class:-

```
public partial class TTTSet
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my get action method:-

```
public ActionResult OrderSettings()
{
    var result = repository.PopulateOrderSettings().ToList();
    return View(result);
}
```

And the repository method:-

```
public IQueryable<TTTSet> PopulateOrderSettings()
{
    return TTT.TTTSets.Where(a => 
        a.Name.ToLower() == "orderformat"
        ||
        a.Name.ToLower() == ("cmread")
        ||
        a.Name.ToLower() == ("cmedit")
        ||
        a.Name.ToLower() == ("aread")
        ||
        a.Name.ToLower() == ("aedit")
        ||
        a.Name.ToLower() == ("sread")
        ||
        a.Name.ToLower() == ("sedit")
    );
```

And my view ,looks as follow:-

```
@model IList<TTT.Models.TTTSet>

int i = 0;

foreach(var s in Model)
{
    @Html.Hidden("TTTSet[" + i.ToString() + "].ID",s.ID)
    @Html.Display("TTTSet[" + i.ToString() + "].Name",s.Name) <text>|</text> @Html.Editor("TTTSet[" + i.ToString() + "].Value",s.Value)
    i++;
}
```

But the final result will be that the `Html.Display` & `Html.Editor` will show empty result, as follow, while the `Html.Hidden` will work well, here is the markup:-

```
<input id="TTTSet_0__ID" name="TTTSet[0].ID" type="hidden" value="105" /> | <input class="text-box single-line" id="TTTSet_0__Value" name="TTTSet[0].Value" type="text" value="" /><input id="TTTSet_1__ID" name="TTTSet[1].ID" type="hidden" value="106" /> | <input class="text-box single-line" id="TTTSet_1__Value" name="TTTSet[1].Value" type="text" value="" /><input id="TTTSet_2__ID" name="TTTSet[2].ID" type="hidden" value="107" /> | <input class="text-box single-line" id="TTTSet_2__Value" name="TTTSet[2].Value" type="text" value="" /><input id="TTTSet_3__ID" name="TTTSet[3].ID" type="hidden" value="108" /> | <input class="text-box single-line" id="TTTSet_3__Value" name="TTTSet[3].Value" type="text" value="" /><input id="TTTSet_4__ID" name="TTTSet[4].ID" type="hidden" value="109" /> | <input class="text-box single-line" id="TTTSet_4__Value" name="TTTSet[4].Value" type="text" value="" /><input id="TTTSet_5__ID" name="TTTSet[5].ID" type="hidden" value="110" /> | <input class="text-box single-line" id="TTTSet_5__Value" name="TTTSet[5].Value" type="text" value="" /><input id="TTTSet_6__ID" name="TTTSet[6].ID" type="hidden" value="111" /> | <input class="text-box single-line" id="TTTSet_6__Value" name="TTTSet[6].Value" type="text" value="" />
```

Can anyone adivce on this please , why the Value and Name are not showing ? could the problem be that my model class has its properties named Name & Value which conflicts with internal names used by the html helpers ? because the ID is showing well as shown in the markup ..

Comment: Do not use a `foreach` loop. Use `for(int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++) { @Html.HiddenFor(m => m[i].ID) @Html.DisplayFor(m => m[i].Name) @Html.EditorFor(m => m[i].Value) }`

Comment: @StephenMuecke i got a syntax error on the view :- Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type

Comment: Then you have not used the code in my comment (all the methods are `xxxFor(...)`

Comment: Make sure you use the `...For` methods as shown, these expect a lambda expression. The methods without `...For` won't work with lambdas.

Comment: And as a side note - the second parameter of `Html.Display()` is the name of the template to use and you would not have any templates with the a name matching `s.Name` which is why it would not render anything.